# SQL Server Combining a defined function with other command

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a defined function to remove HTML from text columns using Dave Pinal's function fro here:  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/

So my SQL command is `dbo.udf_StripHTML([IT Scope]as [IT Scope]`

However, not all tags are removed. I have a two others that seem to come along so was going to use a replace command for them like `replace(replace (replace([IT Scope],'&#160;', ' '),'?', ''),'x','x')` Really to get rid of the `&#160;` and the `?`

Question: I can't really change the function as it will affect many others using the same function on the server. Is there a way to combine these two?
Any thoughts or help is appreciated.

My full script looks like this: (Has both the strip HTML and the replace one line below the other so is not working)

```
Select  
    [ProjectUID], [ProjectName],
    Convert(date, [ProjectStartDate]) as Start,
    Convert(date, [ProjectFinishDate]) as Finish,
    [ProjectPercentCompleted] as [% Completed],
    [ProjectDuration], 
    [ProjectOwnerName] as [Owner],
    [Project Health] as [Health],
    [Project State] as [State],
    [Project Phase] as [Phase],
    [Workstream],
    dbo.udf_StripHTML([Business Scope]) as [Business Scope],
    dbo.udf_StripHTML([IT Scope]),
    replace(replace (replace([IT Scope],'&#160;', ' '),'?', ''),'x','x') as [IT Scope],
    dbo.udf_StripHTML([Status Summary]) as [Status Summary],
    dbo.udf_StripHTML([Recent Accomplishments]) as [Recent Accomplisments],
    dbo.udf_StripHTML([Next Steps]) as [Next Steps],
    [Status Trending],
    [Workstream Lead],
    case [Project Health] 
       when 'Black' then 0
       when 'Green' then 1
       when 'Yellow' then 2
       when 'Red' then 3
       else 4
    end  as [Health2],
    case [Status Trending] 
       when 'Status Unchanged' then 2
       when 'Status Declined' then 1
       when 'Status Improved' then 3
       else 0
    end  as [Trending]
from
    [PSMADO].[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]
Where 
    [Project State] like 'Active'
```

Comment: Changing this line;.         replace(replace (replace([IT Scope],'&#160;', ' '),'?', ''),'x','x') as [IT Scope] with this;        ,replace(replace (replace(udf_striphtml([IT Scope],)'&#160;', ' '),'?', ''),'x','x') as [IT Scope]  doesn't work? It looks like that column you are selecting isn't separated with a comma.

Comment: Else create a new udf with a few extra lines of code might help

Comment: LJ01 You are a genius! this worked ,replace(replace (replace(dbo.udf_StripHTML([IT Scope]),'&#160;', ' '),'?', ''),'x','x') as [IT Scope]

Comment: Added as answer, along with some more explanation cause it seems like the right thing to do... And it's nice of you to say but I'm confident I'm no genius. I have some understanding of sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user defined function can to the best of my knowledge be treated the same as any other functions in SQL. (there may be some scenarios where this is not the case but I can't think of any).

The piece of code you are missing is;

```
replace(replace (replace(udf_striphtml([IT Scope],)'&#160;', ' '),'?', ''),'x','x') as [IT Scope]
```

Another option would be to create a new udf with the extra 2 lines